# Apache mod_rewrite redirect file type to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I use mod_rewrite to send requests for a particular file type to another domain name (server)?

**Example:**

If you request `http://example.com/potato.png` then it'll redirect to `http://anotherdomain.com/potato.png`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a quick solution to redirect images with jpg, gif or png extension to anotherdomain.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://anotherdomain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, example: if you request domain.com/potato.png it'll request domain2.com/potato.png

Comment: @BookOfZeus You are almost there. I would do something like this (one of the possible solutions): `RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://anotherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]`

Comment: Why -- I better leave it for @BookOfZeus to correct his answer (he answered **before** you made your corrections) -- he should easily come up with a different working solution (hint: capture whole name and use `$1`) -- I have enough rep ;) @Bubby4j -- you are free to use any variant :)

Comment: @BookOfZeus i came across your one of your old answer, i am having a bit of a problem with mod_rewrite here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29898156/1478789 and hoping that you could help me with this. I really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Best answer Like